# Deterministic finite automaton (DFA) for regular expression $(a|(bc)^n)^m$

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I constructed a machine for the regular expression $(a|(bc)^n)^m$ where $n,m > 0$. I would be very interested in a correction of the machine, or is the machine in its form correct?

My DFA:

[image]

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Your automaton is not deterministic, since it it missing transitions from all states, e.g. the first state is missing a $c$-transition.

Comment: Ok, if i understand it right, you mean there is missing a "trash" state. So if the first input is c it has to got to the trash state.

Answer (score 1):

Your automata matches the regex given.  It is acceptable to leave out trash states with the understanding that they are implicit.